# Where does a wrapped HandleFunc get responseWriter and request from?

Tags: go

I'm reading "The Way to Go" book and while I understand most, I'm having a difficulty with the following.

The author mentions a way to wrap a HandleFunc in a closure that takes care of panics like so:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<h2>Index</h2>")
}

func logPanics(function HandleFunc) HandleFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
              log.Printf("[%v] caught panic: %v", req.RemoteAddr, err)
            }
        }()
        function(w, req) // Where do w and req come from?
    }
}
```

Later on this is invoked via:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", logPanics(Index))
```

I understand most of it, but wonder how w and req used in

```
function(w, req)
```

get their values? Do I understand correctly, that the w and req in the return statement

```
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)
```

are completely different? Then I wonder, how do w and req get their values. I hope somebody can shed some light on my question as I really want to understand what's going on instead of just copying and pasting.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `http.HandleFunc(path, function)`, it causes the server to invoke `function` when a request is received for the given path.  The function is called with a `*http.Request` describing the request from the client and a `http.ResponseWriter` that can be used to write a response back to the client.

In the following call:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", logPanics(Index))
```

The handler function being registered is the function returned by `logPanics`.  When a request for `/` is received, that function will be called.  That function in turn calls your `Index` function and traps any panics.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I understand correctly, that the w and req in the return statement
>   `return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)`
>   are completely different?

No, not at all, these are the same! Once you delete the defer and
assign the closure to a variable it becomes a bit clearer:

```
func logPanics(function HandleFunc) HandleFunc {
    f := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        function(w, req) // Where do w and req come from?
    }
    return f
}
```

No this code does nothing at all but it is easy to see what goes on: 1) `f` is a function with the proper signature (taking a ResponseWriter and a Request). 2) All it does is call the function passed to `logPanics` with the argument it was called. 3) This function `f` is returned.